# Division of a quadratic polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $f(x)$ is a quadratic polynomial. when $f(x)$ is divided by 
>   $(x-1),(x-2)$, and $(x+2)$ the remainders respectively are $-1, 4$, and $2$. How do you find $f(x)$ in a question like this?

I've tried to do it using the Polynomial remainder theorem, but it needs the quotient also, so to find the answer for this question we can't use the mentioned theorem.

Comment: Hint: $f(1)=-1$, $f(2)=4$, and $f(-2)=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$. Using the first factor and remainder, you can write $f(x) = (x - 1)q(x) - 1$. Now evaluate both of these at $x = 1$. Note that you don't need the quotient. Now repeat for the other two factors and remainders. Can you see how to go on?

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=a(x-1)(x-2)+b(x-2)(x+2)+c(x-1)(x+2)$$ where $a,b,c$ are arbitrary constants

Set $x=1,-2,+2$ to find $a,b,c$